# The setItem function is working fine in Reactjs but localStorage.getItem is not working

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks, local-storage

In the code I change some recipe content and it saves but when I refresh my page it resets everything and the changes are gone

Here is my code

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "cookingWithKyle.recipes"

function App() {
  const [selectedRecipeId, setSelectedRecipeId] = useState()
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState(sampleRecipe)
  const selectedRecipe = recipes.find(
    (recipe) => recipe.id === selectedRecipeId
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    const recipeJSON = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)
    if (recipeJSON) setRecipes(JSON.parse(recipeJSON))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(recipes))
  }, [recipes])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, in React `useEffect` hook's callback is run asynchronously. So, you cannot control which callback is processed first and end before another.

But here, the main reason of your issue is, even if you have *recipes* as a dependency in your second `useEffect`, second useEffect's callback will also be fired on initial mount (on page reload), thus in your code you set a value (probably undefined) to your localStorage and then try to get a value, which was already gone.
So, try to run your second `useEffect`'s callback with a condition:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (recipes) {
       localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(recipes))
   }
}, [recipes])
```

For information, React fires the `useEffect` hooks callback when it compares dependency list in an array with a previous render (so, try not to use a value of *object* type as a dependency, otherwise your callback will be fired in every render) and if it sees the difference, it fires `useEffect`'s callback, **including the initial render**.

Comment: So I delayed the second effect so that it only sets to localStorage after setRecipes has been set initially. By checing the recipe is not the sampleRecipe and it worked.
   ``` if (recipes!==sampleRecipe) {
      localStorage.setItem('cookingWithKyle.recipes', JSON.stringify(recipes))
  }
  }, [recipes])```